# Are questions asking about problems encountered while following a tutorial off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've noticed that these sorts of questions are suddenly being closed:

- ["Minecraft Properties" tab is not showing up on rig where the tab is supposed to be there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33148/599)
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33147/599

However these weren't always closed, for instance [Cause of black artifacts in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/599) (from one of the same tutorials even).

I feel like we should decide one way or another.

---

I don't really see any difference between these questions and the usual "Something X is weird, why?" questions.
Are there any reasons to exclude these kinds of questions from our scope?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little contentious, but in the case of "What face do I extrude in this tutorial?" it's a little bit like helping someone with a paint-by-numbers painting. It's not teaching them to paint, it's us showing them how to do the thing that should have been made clear in the tutorial.

They weren't having a problem with the concept of *extrude*, but the problem with the clarity of the tutorial, and that's why I think we should not encourage questions like that.

But there are questions about tutorials which I think are valid to answer once, for example scripting tutorials which reference deprecated API (for example the CGcookie AudioVisualizer tutorial. I think it generated about 5 questions here, and maybe 10 question on BA.org).

There's a nuance here which might not be easy to enforce or get agreement on.